# How to update column with foreign key constraint within same table

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I want to update an ID-column of a table that is referenced in a foreign key constraint within that same table.

Example code:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  A_id int,
  parent_A_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (A_id),
  CONSTRAINT parent_A FOREIGN KEY (parent_A_id) REFERENCES A (A_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO A VALUES (0, NULL), (1, 0);
```

Now I try to update the column `A_id` with

```
UPDATE A SET A_id = A_id + 1;
```

Unfortunately this throws an error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I don't really understand why this fails and I can't find anything in the MySQL docs mentioning this not being allowed.
So, why does this not work?

And in the case that I don't just do a stupid mistake:
Is there any better way of doing such an update other than setting `foreign_key_checks = 0` and doing everything by hand?

My problem with this would be that I'd like to use the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to let the DB handle all foreign key updates for me.

Comment: Don’t update the primary key, that is a very bad idea for any table

Comment: I need to migrate data from an older database to a newer one. I wanted to copy the data first and fix some IDs later to keep the code simple.

Comment: @Felck Select everything into a table with no constraints on it, then add the constraints at the end.

Comment: @ChuckAdams This works fine if there are no other foreign key constraints referencing `A_id` in other tables. I'd really like to use the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` behavior and leave it to the DB to update all foreign keys accordingly.

Comment: Based on what you're needing to do, your constraint looks backwards to me. Trying to update `A_ID`, but it is the child and will not be allowed. I think you need `FOREIGN KEY (A_id) REFERENCES A (parent_A_id)`. It's not apparent which should be the primary in your question.

Comment: @Felck if you're messing with primary keys, you're pretty much going to have to redo every single table touching them.  It'd be easier if mysql supported deferred constraints (even freaking sqlite supports them these days) but alas you're looking at migrating pretty much everything that references that table.  Possibly migrate the tables to a design where you don't have to pull off such chicanery -- which I'm still not convinced is justified in the first place, but I don't have enough info to know for sure.